# Save a canvas as an image on Electron

Tags: javascript, electron, fs

My current setup:

1. Convert canvas to blob.
2. Ask the user for a file path.
3. Save the blob at the location given by the user.

However, I can't get step 3 to work. I'm currently trying to use fs to do the job, but it doesn't really seem to save the file.

Current code:

```
canvas.toBlob(blob => {
    remote.dialog.showSaveDialog({ defaultPath: "file.png" }).then((canceled, filepath) => {
        if (filepath) { // Using filepath because canceled is always true for some reason
            blob.arrayBuffer().then(arrayBuffer => {
                console.log(arrayBuffer);
                fs.writeFile(filepath, Buffer.from(arrayBuffer), err => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
            });
        }
    });
}, "image/png");
```

Are there any flaws in my code? I tried changing the Buffer to Uint8Array and Int8Array, but they didn't work either.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: you could try add some `console.log` in the callback passed to `writeFile`, after `if (err) throw err` to make sure that this async operation has completed.

Comment: There are no errors in the console, and there is already `if (err) throw err;` in the writeFile callback.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing canceled/filepath argument into one result argument which holds all of them, turns out I was just using showSaveDialog in a wrong way.